# React JS : CCAvenue Payment Integration

Tags: javascript, reactjs, payment-gateway, payment-processing, ccavenue

I want to integrate CC Avenue Payment gateway in my React JS Application.
When I click on Payment button, it should open CC Avenue payment window to make payment and after successful of payment , I want to get its response and redirect to thankyou page.

Below is the code i have tried.

I have installed [Node CCAvenue](https://www.npmjs.com/package/node-ccavenue) plugin.

```js
const nodeCCAvenue = require('node-ccavenue');
const ccav = new nodeCCAvenue.Configure({
  merchant_id: XXXXXXX,
  working_key: XXXXXXXXXXXXXX,
});

const orderParams = {
  order_id: 123456,
  currency: 'INR',
  amount: '100',
  redirect_url: encodeURIComponent(`URL`),
  billing_name: 'John Doe',
  // etc etc
};
 
const encryptedOrderData = ccav.getEncryptedOrder(orderParams);
```

what URL should I put in `redirect_url` so that it can open Payment window.

Any help would be great.

Thank You.

Comment: I think the url should be your site redirection once the payment is processed

Comment: can anyone help me to implement ccavenue payment integration in react native

Comment: Is the issue resolved @Vishali

Comment: @AmiKamboj i haven't found any solution still now

Answer (score 1):

I'm the author of the node-ccavenue module so I think can answer this.

Don't use the node-ccavenue package on your client side with React. The module uses Node.js' crypto library to encode and decode order information. Additionally, you cannot expose your merchant_id or working_key by putting them in clientside scripts.

Use this in your backend code if your backend is written with Node.js and return the encryptedOrderData to the frontend via an api endpoint

Comment: Hi, I'm struggling integrating CCAvenue payment gateway in my react app, we've done the server side setup and the API's are working but in client side, after payment completion or if user cancels the payment, there is no way for me to get the values returned after redirection, can you help me with that.